# How do I define Ruby on Rails route using regex based constraints to ignore blacklisted word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes

I have a virtual server set up that points to a page on a Rails app. I am having issue defining the route to ignore BLACKLIST_WORD when my GET requests hit mysite.com/BLACKLIST_WORD. Here is what I do, unfortunately, it does not work.

```
  get '*ignore_me' => 'pages#unknown_url' , :constraints => { :ignore_me => /^/(?!BLACKLIST_WORD/).+/ }
```

My unknown_url method does additional processing with the requests but I want that for anything blacklisted. Please help, cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did.

```
get '*path', to: 'pages#unknown_url', constraints: BlacklistConstraint.new

class BlacklistConstraint
  def initialize
    # @ips = Blacklist.retrieve_ips
    @word_list = [
      "/BLACKLIST_WORD"
    ]
  end

  def matches?(request)
    # @ips.include?(request.remote_ip)
    puts request.path
    if @word_list.include?(request.path)
      return false
    else
      return true
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having checked it, but I guess you have to escape the `/`

So should be

```
/^\/(?!BLACKLIST_WORD\/).+/
```

maybe the 2nd `/` even optional? `\/?`